# Fetching all attribute names that have the same value in Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Say you have a Core Data model with Entity `Subjects` and Attributes `Algebra, Biology, Calculus, Chemistry, Physics`, like this:

```
Subjects
======
Algebra  (Boolean)
Biology  (Boolean)
Calculus  (Boolean)
Chemistry  (Boolean)
Physics  (Boolean)
```

Let's say that Algebra, Calculus, and Physics are `true` while Biology and Chemistry haven't yet been assigned values. How can I get the array: `["Algebra", "Calculus", "Physics"]`? I would think it involves NSPredicate but I'm really not sure how to do it.

And as a side question, would default values matter here? i.e., should I make everything start off as false?

Thank you!

Comment: Use something lie  `NSPredicate(format: "Algebra = %d AND Calculus = %d", true, true)`

Comment: What does the boolean value represent?  It sounds like your Subject entity should have two attributes, a string `name` and a boolean.  You would then have a different instance of that entity for each of the subjects, “Algebra”, “Biology”, etc.  Then you can use a predicate to fetch those subjects where the boolean is true.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks, but how would I do it if I didn't know which subjects are true? i.e. I need a way to parse through all the attributes and fetch them only if their value is true. Not sure if/how loops can work with Core Data.

Comment: @pbasdf I definitely get what you're saying but I think I'd like to do things a little unconventionally to fit my app's goals. Let's say that there's a long list of subjects, and as users "learn" them (through other parts of the app), they are marked as `true`. Then I want to be able to tell them what all the subjects that they have learned are. So I'm looking to go through all the subjects and find the ones that have been marked as `true`. Does that make sense? Thank you for your response.

Comment: It makes sense - but I still recommend my approach.  How and why is too long for comments, so I'll work up an answer for you to ponder.

Comment: I think @pbasdf is correct and I was thinking about this solution myself and also note that you can't fetch separate attributes based on a predicate so again a different design solution could help.

Comment: Thanks so much, @pbasdf. Looking forward to seeing what you write up! I'm admittedly very inexperienced with Core Data and frankly iOS development in general. But since I have built in information about all of the subjects (such as equations that users learn and stuff like that) stored in `Subject` custom objects, I wasn't sure how Core Data could interact with all that. It doesn't fit the typical "adding companies to a tableview" structure that I've seen in many Core Data examples. Would I need to eliminate my `Subject` custom object and instead store all that info in Core Data? (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) @pbasdf If so, how would I store the built in information as instances of the Subject entity? For all the different subjects. Maybe something with default values? Sorry for the rather convoluted questioning, and perhaps your write-up will respond to some of these queries. Thank you again!

Comment: @JoakimDanielson got it, didn't realize that you couldn't fetch attributes based on a predicate. I'm working to switch from Firebase to Core Data and am finding that my data structure there is unfortunately not very conducive to Core Data. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You propose an entity named `Subjects`, with attributes named `Algebra`, `Biology`, etc, each of which is a boolean that represents whether the user has "learned" that subject.  From that, you wish to compose an array comprising all the names of the subjects that the user has learnt.

Although that is possible, it's quite difficult.  I recommend instead defining your `Subject` entity as:

```
Subject
=======
name (String)
learnt (boolean)
```

(Note the convention that entity names are usually singular and start with uppercase, whereas attribute names begin with lowercase.)  In the first run of your app you might then create a number of instances of the `Subject` entity, with the required default values:

```
name        learnt
====        ======
"Algebra"   false
"Biology"   false
"Calculus"  false
...         ...
```

This has the advantage that you can add further subjects at a later date, without needing to modify the structure of your data: it is a simple matter of creating an additional instance with the appropriate `name`.

As your user progresses through their learning in the app, you can set the value for the `learnt` attribute to `true` for the relevant `Subject` instance.  To obtain an array containing only those `Subject` instances which the user has successfully learnt, you can then use a fetch request with a predicate:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"learnt == true")
```

The array that is returned contains the relevant instances of the `Subject` entity.  It is then simple to obtain the names for display purposes.

You mention in comments having further information about all the subjects.  If you model all that in CoreData (eg. having `Topic`, `Lesson`, `Test` entities, etc - I speculate, that's for you to design) you can create relationships to that data from your `Subject` entity.  For example, a `Subject` might have a relationship to many `Topics`, each of which has many `Lessons` and many `Tests`, etc.  That way, when your app starts, you can fetch all the `Subject` instances and display them in a tableView (showing the `name` attribute).  When the user taps a Subject to begin or continue their learning, you have the relevant `Subject` instance which provides the link (via the relevant relationship) for you to display the material for the chosen subject.

Comment: This is great, thank you so much!! Really appreciate your thorough response. I do have a follow-up if you wouldn't mind...could you point me in the right direction to creating all those `Subject` instances when the app first starts so that the user can begin to make their way through learning everything? I've been googling around about preloading data/initializing instances when the app first launches but I'm having some difficulties. This is something that I would just want to happen one time, when the app first launches, to not create duplicates of course.

Comment: It depends on the volume of data that you want to preload.  If there's a lot, it can be worth pre-populating a CoreData database and including that with you app's bundle.  For smaller amounts, you might use a plist, or JSON or similar which you then process into CoreData during the first app launch.  Either way, many people put the requisite code in the AppDelegate.

Comment: Got it, thank you! You've been super helpful, much appreciated. All the best!